# Access 2010 How to save password when creating linked table

Tags: ms-access-2010, linked-tables

I have an Access 2010 database with linked tables that connect to a sql server database.  I do not have the connections set as a trusted connection, instead I want the linked tables to connect to the sql server login and password I provide.  For users who are accessing this over our network it is still prompting for the password even though it displays the login id.  Is there a way to make Access save the password as well in Access?

Answer (score 3):

I found that in order to save a password in the DSN, I had to create a File DSN and in that file I had to be sure to include a field for the password such as:

PWD=mypassword

But there is a risk of exposing the password in a file.  Ultimately, we decided that it was better to make users enter the password, which will be prompted for on just the first time they try to get a result from a query or table after they open the Access database file.